# event triggered by backspace key but not delete key

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, keycode

I have a form field which uses Jorn Zaefferer's "autocomplete" jQuery plugin.  If i type some text, then select part of it and hit backspace, the autocomplete list updates.  But if i hit delete instead of backspace, the autocomplete list disappears.

I'm looking at the code for the plugin and it looks like the autocomplete updater is triggered by a keydown event in the field, and both backspace and delete trigger a keydown.

Is there a fundamental difference between backspace and delete that could be causing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [`onChange()` method](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js), <kbd>Del</kbd> has a special purpose - to hide the autocomplete list:

```
function onChange(crap, skipPrevCheck) {
    if( lastKeyPressCode == KEY.DEL ) {
        select.hide();
        return;
    }
```

So no, there's no fundamental difference in event behavior here, this is just how the autocomplete plugin is designed, the delete key is specifically intended to hide the list.

Comment: aha!  off to hack the plugin then...yup, commenting out those four lines sorted it.  Thanks Nick!